# Displaying Formula Field as a string rather than a boolean in CR9

Tags: string, crystal-reports, boolean, formula, crystal-reports-2008

I've got a formula field in my Crystal 9 report, which is taking a number field from the database and converting it to a string, which is stored in a `stringVar`.

If the number is less than 1000 (< 1000), the `stringVar` then concatenates 0 onto the front, to make all of the strings 4 digits long (Can't be more than this, due to the format in the program I've written).

I'm trying to use this formula field to display the 4 digit `stringVar`, but it's outputting either `True` or `False`, rather than the string.

Why is this, what needs changing?

```
stringVar ACP := CStr ({Acquisition_Commission.AqYear});

If {Acquisition_Commission.AqYear} < 1000 Then
   ACP = "0"  & ACP
Else
   ACP = ACP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using toText function and left padding right trim

```
right("0000" & toText({Acquisition_Commission.AqYear},0,""),4)
```

Comment: Actually, the top 2 still only displayed either `True` or `False`. The third method displayed just meaningless, random decimals (2.00 and 4.00, for example). The last one works, though, so thanks.